# What would I round this answer to for significant figures?

Tags: significant-figures

25-6.1=18.9   It's subtraction, so I round to the least number of decimal places. But will my final answer be 18 or 19?

Answer (score 0):

You round to the closer number and $19$ is much closer than $18$.